# Using git from the command line after installing Github for Mac

Tags: macos, git, github, github-for-mac

I installed Github for Mac, which works fine, but I can't run git commands from Terminal. Do I have another git that needs to be installed? Or do I have to enable some optio within Github for Mac?

Comment: You now can install git CLI with "GitHub for Mac". See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting May 2013 ("[Installing Git from GitHub for Mac](https://github.com/blog/1510-installing-git-from-github-for-mac)"), you don't have to install another git distribution: everything is included.

> you can now easily install Git for use on the command line, without needing to download any separate packages.
>   And whenever we update the version of Git included with GitHub for Mac, you'll get the changes automatically – no work required on your part!
>
> you may notice some changes to the Preferences window.
>   On the newly renamed "`Advanced`" tab, simply click "`Install Command Line Tools`".
>
> You'll be prompted for an administrator password so that Git can be installed into `/usr/local/bin`, and then you should very shortly see that it succeeded:

[image]

Comment: I've done it, but typing "git" from the terminal, a popup prompts and says the I must install xcode for developer tools... what is the problem?

Comment: @mikecurl91 is it a terminal you launched from the GitHub for Mac GUI?

Comment: yes, it is! and trying to type the same in the terminal (opened outside the github mac client), the result is the same!

Comment: @mikecurl91 so, I suppose: http://eventuallyquality.blogspot.fr/2013/10/install-command-line-tools-in-osx-109.html or https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/PublishYourCodetoaSourceRepository/PublishYourCodetoaSourceRepository.html should help? `xcode-select --install`

Comment: @mikecurl91 other solution: http://panic.com/qa/discussion/comment/353#Comment_353

Comment: but, after I've installed Command Line Tools from Github Mac app, I'll navigate to usr/local/bin where these tools are, and "Git" there is! but when I try to execute it, typing "git", the result is:
michele$ git
xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.

Comment: Github mac app installs Git, doesn't?

Comment: @mikecurl91 yes, it should.

Answer (score 0):

Git can be installed in a number of ways on OSX:

1) If you have [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) installed, you can install it through that by opening up a terminal and doing:

```
sudo port install git
```

2) Download it from the official site & mount & install the .dmg: http://git-scm.com/download/mac

Answer (score 0):

https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#platform-mac has instructions on setting up git for the command line. (essentially download http://git-scm.com/download/mac and setup the config)

Note for windows users you can use a workaround program called "Git Bash" to approximate a unix like command line from which you can execute git commands.