# Error when setting up Git Identity

Tags: github

Completely new to Github. I downloaded Git of OSX (10.7.5) and opened the terminal.

I entered

```
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
```

and was returned with

```
-bash: $: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think `git` is not installed properly on your machine.

Comment: Try typing `which git` to see if it's installed. For example, when I do that, I see `/usr/bin/git`. Most developers don't have to install `git` separately because it comes with Xcode. (download it from the app store.) You probably want Xcode anyway, so you can use things like MacPorts or HomeBrew. (unless you JUST want SCM and don't really want to do much development.)

Comment: which git returns an unknown error.

Comment: @JoeIsaacson if `which git` did return an unknown error. then you have problems with your OS which should either print a path on stdout or do nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have downloaded the "[GitHub for Mac](http://mac.github.com/)" app, then you need to open a command-line.

See "[Using git from the command line after installing Github for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16664015/6309)":

You can actually ask for the installation of the command-line from the GitHub for Mac app itself!

[image: install]

Answer (score 0):

Git is most probably not properly installed on your machine. Please follow this guide to install git again.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Comment: Followed the Mac Installation Directions. Opened up the zip. Saved the Githup app in my applications.

Comment: @JoeIsaacson, it sounds like you downloaded the GitHub app, which is different than (more likely built upon) the git software itself. If you want to install git without downloading other development tools, try the version [here](http://git-scm.com/download/mac).