# Git and Github Mac App incompatibilities?

Tags: xcode, git, osx-mavericks, github-for-mac

After I've installed Github Mac app on my macbook (running OSX Mavericks 10.9.2), I've tried to type git on the terminal, and a message appears and say:

```
xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.
```

I've also already installed the "Command Line Tools" from Github Mac app preferences.
So, what is the problem?
Why I can not use the "git" terminal commands and Github Mac client app together?
I've search over the web for solutions, but anyone resolves my problem.

Comment: So http://panic.com/qa/discussion/comment/353#Comment_353 that I mentioned previously (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872760/using-git-from-the-command-line-after-installing-github-for-mac/16664015#comment34649529_16664015) didn't help?

Comment: It didn't :| the problem persists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `xcode-select --install`.

As far as I understand, the command line tools are compilers and other tools needed for development.

For background: prior to Xcode 5, you used to have to download Xcode and within Xcode's preferences choose 'Install Command Line Tools' (or use the command I listed above).

Edit: Corrects the install flag syntax

Comment: are "command line tools" you've mentioned, the same "command line tools" that Github mac app suggests to install?

Comment: I don't use the GitHub client so I don't know what tools it may install. But that error message you are receiving suggests you need to `xcode-select install`.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, it fails. This message appears: "Print or change the path to the active developer directory. This directory
controls which tools are used for the Xcode command line tools (for example, 
xcodebuild) as well as the BSD development commands (such as cc and make)."

Comment: Sorry, its `xcode-select --install`. (Note the dashes). I'll edit the answer.